# Android studio fails to resolve specific resource. Does compile, and does resolve R

Tags: android, android-studio

So after updating to the latest android studio 4.1.1 I've noticed that the IDE fails to resolve specific resources in project files. For example, while it does successfully resolve `R` and `R.string` it does not resolve `R.string.ok`, despite ok being in the `strings.xml` file (and it did resolve this prior to the upgrade).

The IDE *does* successfully resolve resource reference in layout files, just not in Kotlin code.

I've tried `build > clean` and `invalidate caches and restart`. Neither of which seemed to have helped at all.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

At this point I'm pretty sure that this is a result of a bug in the latest version of Android Studio. I rolled it back to 4.0.1 from 4.1.1 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what I missed before but I fixed my issue by erasing the local repository and recloning.
I wish I could be more specific as to which local cache was the problem, I don't *think* it was the .gradle folder as I *think* I tried deleting that already, without anything working.

-- Update --

Note that the issue occurred again after this fix. I don't know whats causing the problem to begin with, however. This time I ran  `rm -rf .gradle/ local.properties .idea/caches/ .idea/libraries/ .idea/modules.xml .idea/workspace.xml .idea/navEditor.xml .DS_Store build` to fix it rather than deleting + recloning. If and when this issue reoccurs, I'll trim that command down to see if I can pinpoint which component is getting corrupted.

-- Update 2 --

Issue happened again. This time I went through closing Android Studio + deleting folders/files + restarting Android Studio one at a time in that above list.

It appears that `rm .idea/modules.xml` is sufficient to fix the problem. I may open up a new issue in the future regarding *why* this keeps on happening.